# How to show help on backslash commands in psql for `\c` command?

Tags: psql

When I inside `psql` I can invoke help with `\?`.

```
...
Help
  \? [commands]          show help on backslash commands
  \? options             show help on psql command-line options
  \? variables           show help on special variables
  \h [NAME]              help on syntax of SQL commands, * for all commands
...
```

But when I tried to get help only for `\c` command `\? \c` I get same output as it was for invoked `\?`.

How to show help on backslash commands in psql for `\c`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: `\? [commands]` Looks like it takes an argument. Found `\c[onnect] {[DBNAME|- USER|- HOST|- PORT|-] | conninfo}`. It looks a bit ambigious: `\c db - user` does not work. Though `\c db user` works well. What does `|-` stands for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-QUESTION-MARK), you'll see

> `? [ topic ]`
>
> Shows help information. The optional `topic` parameter (defaulting to `commands`) selects which part of psql is explained: `commands` describes psql's backslash commands; `options` describes the command-line options that can be passed to psql; and `variables` shows help about psql configuration variables.

So you cannot display help on a single backslash command; your options are:

```
\? commands
\? options
\? variables
```

If you look at the `\?` output, you will note that `\? [command]` has `command` in lower case. In other cases, where you can supply a variable argument to the command, it is shown in upper case, for example `\e [FILE] [LINE]`. So that `command` means the literal string `command`, it is not a placeholder for a command.

I freely admit that this is somewhat confusing, but I cannot think of an improvement that is short enough.

Comment: Short improvement: `\? [commands]          show help on backslash commands (see output below)` or something similar

Comment: wow!! Thanks for the link to the documentations. I never thought that `commands` is literal. How about `\? [TOPIC]          show help on topic: commands, options, variables`. Also **topic** on that page of documentation should be uppercased, to follow convention you described here.